# Prove the orthogonality of these curves

Tags: derivatives, curves, implicit-differentiation

I am having trouble proving the orthogonality of the following curves: $$\begin{cases} x = \frac{1}{2}(v_1^2 - v_2^2), v_1=\text{const} \\ y = v_1v_2, v_2=\text{const} \end{cases}$$

Here's everything I know (and tried):

I've been told that in order to check the orthogonality of the given curves, for this problem we need to see if using the formula for scalar multiplication of gradients $(\text{grad}x, \text{grad}y)$ we get $0$. However, I am having trouble actually setting up the gradients even before scalar multiplication. Any ideas on how to derive the gradients here?

$$∇f=(∂x/∂f, ∂y/∂f)$$
How exactly do we find $∂x/∂f$ and $∂y/∂f$ for the system with constants?

Comment: The problem statement and my background is updated. I ask for the reopening of the question.

Comment: Not much better. The confusing issues are still unclear. And you’ve added $\partial x/\partial f$, which makes no sense. However, it does seem that my first interpretation of the problem was correct, after all.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I've got confirmation that it was correct. Now what I've been suggested was to check for orthogonality using scalar multiplication of gradients. Can you please give any hints on how do you actually compute them for this problem, since you are implying the formula makes no sense?

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you provide any tips on how to improve this question? What exactly are the confusing issues. I am now thinking of editing it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's written, the problem is very confusing.

**Here is my first interpretation:** The curves are obtained by setting $x$ and $y$ constant. Then differentiate with respect to $v_1$ implicitly:

\begin{align*}
0 &= v_1 - v_2\,\dfrac{dv_2}{dv_1} \\
0 &= v_2 + v_1\,\dfrac{dv_2}{dv_1}.
\end{align*}

So you have slope $\dfrac{dv_2}{dv_1}$ equal to $\dfrac{v_1}{v_2}$ for the first curve and $-\dfrac{v_2}{v_1}$ for the second curve. They are indeed negative reciprocals.

**Here is what is probably the intended interpretation:** The $v_1$ and $v_2$ constant should *not* be adjacent to $x$ and $y$ at all, but describe how we obtain the curves from $x$ and $y$ as functions of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

We have $x=\frac12v_1^2-\frac12v_2^2$ and $y=v_1v_2$. We obtain the first curve by setting $v_1$ constant and varying $v_2$; so
$$\frac{dx}{dv_2} = -v_2, \quad \frac{dy}{dv_2} = v_1.$$
For the second curve we set $v_2$ constant and vary $v_1$; so
$$\frac{dx}{dv_1} = v_1, \quad \frac{dy}{dv_1} = v_2.$$
The first curve has slope
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dv_2}}{\frac{dx}{dv_2}} = \frac{v_1}{-v_2},$$
while the second has slope
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dv_1}}{\frac{dx}{dv_1}} = \frac{v_2}{v_1}.$$
These slopes are indeed negative reciprocals.

Comment: I doubt that "the curves are obtained by setting $x$ and $y$ constant".

Comment: @Anne, as I said, the problem is very confusing. As it stands, they have $x$ and $y$ in terms of two different parameters, so the phrases $v_1=\text{constant}$ and $v_2=\text{constant}$ have nothing to do with $x$ and $y$. This may be a bad problem or it may be a bad job of typesetting.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your answer. I agree that the problem's formulation is confusing indeed, but your solution seems genuine.

Comment: Besides, could you also give some tips or information on how to graph those curves by any chance?

Comment: Just for the record, my second solution is the same thing @Anne wrote above, but I did it a bit more like a beginning calculus student might do it. Fix constant $a$ and you want to graph $x=\frac12 a^2-\frac12 t^2$, $y=at$. The easiest way for you to do that is to eliminate the $t$ and write $x=\frac12a^2-\frac12(y/a)^2$, which is a hyperbola. Similarly for $x=\frac12 u^2-\frac12b^2$, $y=bu$. Then $x=\frac12(y/b)^2-\frac12b^2$ is a different hyperbola.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the information. Just for clarification, am I correct to interpret that $x=\frac12a^2-\frac12(y/a)^2$ is for curve $\frac{1}{2}(v_1^2-v_2^2), v_1=\text{const}$ and $x=\frac12(y/b)^2-\frac12b^2$ for curve $y=v_1v_2, v_2=\text{const}$?

Comment: No, you’re still misinterpreting the problem. You have to read carefully what I typed. And you should check with your professor. The $v_1$ constant does not go with $x$ and the $v_2$ constant does not go with $y$. The problem is terribly presented.

Comment: I am confused, is it wrong with the solution, or are the equations for graphs wrong?

Comment: The question as it was stated makes no sense. I carefully suggested how one can make sense of it and solved it. You just keep restating it as it originally made no sense. I strongly urge you to talk with the person who wrote the problem and ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I now have the correct statement for the problem. I will post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your two (families of) curves seem to be
$$C_r:c(s)=((r^2-s^2)/2,rs)$$
and
$$\Gamma_s:\gamma(r)=((r^2-s^2)/2,rs).$$
At some point $((r^2-s^2)/2,rs)\in C_r\cap\Gamma_s$, the tangent to $C_r$ is directed by $c'(s)=(-s,r)$ and the tangent to $\Gamma_s$ is directed by $\gamma'(r)=(r,s)$.

These two vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, I think it's too technical for me. I am supposed to do simple differentiation here, but I am not entirely sure about it.

Comment: "Simple differentiation" *is* what I did, for your two parametrized (families of) curves.